# How to match file name using php fnmatch or other match expression

Tags: php

I have a little code to match user uploading image name with existing image name,
I was able to archive this by using

```
<?php
$newName = "foo.png"
if(file_exists("images/" . $newName)){
echo "Image already exist";
}
?>
```

The above code worked for me, but when new image is `foo.jpg` it will insert new it as new image.
So now that i always rename the user image to his username making sure that the file name is same but extension can be different how can i match this? the below code didn't work

```
<?php
$NewImage = "foo.jpg";
if(fnmatch($_SESSION['username'], $NewImage )) {
  echo "This image already exist";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work, because you are testing exact match.
First argument is *The shell wildcard pattern.* (as stated in [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php)), so you need to use wildcard instead of image extension, like this:

```
$result = fnmatch('foo.*', $fileName);
```

Comment: @iku How do i use it?